# Function being called but not executing

Tags: swift, closures, custom-operator

I have this custom operator:

```
infix operator ?> : NilCoalescingPrecedence
func ?> (lhs: Any?, rhs: @autoclosure ()->Any) {
    if lhs == nil {
        print("lhs is nil")
        rhs()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
optional ?> {
    print("executing")
}
```

The problem is, when the `lhs` is nil, the closure is not executing. In the console "lhs is nil" is printing, but no "executing" is printing afterwards. How is the "lhs is nil" print statement executed but not `rhs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be add an overload to the operator with exactly the same signature, except for that it doesn't have the `@autoclosure` annotation, and the `rhs` for both has to return `Void` instead of `Any`.

```
infix operator ?> : NilCoalescingPrecedence
func ?> (lhs: Any?, rhs: @autoclosure ()->Void) {
    if lhs == nil {
        print("lhs is nil")
        rhs()
    }
}
func ?> (lhs: Any?, rhs: ()->Void) {
    if lhs == nil {
        print("lhs is nil")
        rhs()
    }
}
```

This way if I do:

```
optional ?> doSomething()
```

the  `@autoclosure` one will get called, regardless of whether `doSomething()` returns anything or not.

And if I do:

```
optional ?> {
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

the one without the `@autoclosure` will be called because the closure is of type `()->Void`.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that causes this behaviour is `@autoclosure`, if you remove it, it works fine.

This is because `@autoclosure` will wrap your closure into a closure, so now you have something like this:

```
{ { print("executing") } }
```

The outer closure returns `Any`, right? So it will just return the closure `{ print("executing") }` and do nothing else.

If you want to keep the `@autoclosure`, you can use the operator this way:

```
optional ?> print("executing")
```

Comment: what if i want to be able to do `optional ?> print("executing")` and `optional ?> { print("executing"); ...}`?

Comment: I think you just need to write another overload. Haven't tested though. @shoe

Comment: it was a little more than that, but i provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45248170/6744473) to demonstrate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `()` at the end of the closure method like below

```
optional ?> {
    print("executing")
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention that curly braces *must* be added after the operator, you could implement it (without the need of declaring `rhs` as autoclosure) as:

```
infix operator ?> : NilCoalescingPrecedence

func ?> (lhs: Any?, rhs: ()->Any) {
    if lhs == nil {
        print("lhs is nil")
        rhs()
    }
}

var myString: String? = ""

// some case that made "string" to be nil...
myString = nil

myString ?> {
    print("executing")
}
```

However, the purpose of declaring autoclosure is to wrap an expression that’s being passed as an argument to a function:

> This syntactic convenience lets you omit braces around a function’s
>   parameter by writing a normal expression instead of an explicit
>   closure.
>
> <sub>[The Official Swift Documentation - Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), Autoclosures</sub>

which means that there is no need to the curly braces, which should be more natural when working with an operator:

```
infix operator ?> : NilCoalescingPrecedence

func ?> (lhs: Any?, rhs: @autoclosure ()->Any) {
    if lhs == nil {
        print("lhs is nil")
        rhs()
    }
}

 var myString: String? = ""

 // some case that made "string" to be nil...
 myString = nil

// you could use your operator like:
 myString ?> print("executing")
```

**But Wait!**

There is an issue might be faced which is: what if a chunk of code should be added  after the operator?

Well, no doubt you have to add the curly braces:

```
let doSomething = {
    print("executing")
    print("second line of execution")
    print("third line of execution")
}

myString ?> doSomething()
```